# Which GCC version is preferred on an AARCH64 platform with CentOS7.4?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, centos7, arm64

We have some servers with ARM CPU and will test some SW applications. With Ubuntu system, there is no big problem because the kernel and the SW are quite up-to-date. But with CentOS system, some tools and libs are quite old on ARM. For example, the GCC compiler is still 4.8.5 and some features couldn't be supported.

On X86_64, this is not a problem, because there are SCL and other sources with stable packages.

On ARM, now I find to choices, one is from RH and the other is from Linaro.

**https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/**

The Linaro project provide some source of GCC5, 6 and 7. We could build and run on the system. Ubuntu ARM version is using the GCC from Linaro right now. But on the release notes, it just mentions Ubuntu but no CentOS support. (Even this could be done on CentOS)

**https://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/aarch64/rh/**

The RH also provide the GCC for aarch64 as on the X86_64 computer/server. But now it is still in the test repository but not the official update sources. And only GCC6 and 7 are provided.

So any suggestion? Should I use the test version from centos.org or the source code from Linaro.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the ARM CPU Servers are you targetting, the vendor may also provide you with the OS and packages/repo which is recommended to be used.

Linaro might be a better pick than the test repo (expected to be more stable) in the case that you are doing some functional/performance testing of SW applications. Even though centos7.4 is not stated as officially supported platforms, its worth a try. Its likely that the Linaro GCC toolchain will just work on the OS of your choice.

You may also download the latest GCC from the public mirrors and try, say one of the GCC 7 releases (At the moment, the latest is gcc 7.3.0 https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/). Aarch64/Aarch32 are supported targets.

Whatever you chose, ARM CPU server ecosystem is actively evolving as these chips are just hitting the market. You might want to check which of the above (Linaro/GCC/RH) is being actively contributed to in the area of the target platform of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information, Cherry. It seems that Linaro and Ubuntu are a little more active than the RH in the ARM ecosystem. It might be the gene and culture of the companies/organization. Sometimes the RH may focus on the stability but not so eager for the new features or patches which may cause any new problems. Is my understanding right?